# Text Field should show 1 when i press 1 but it didnt. why?

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
public class Scal {

    JFrame mainframe;
    JPanel controlsPanel;
    JPanel inputPanel;
    JPanel opPanel;
    JTextField inputbox;
    String input1 = "";

    public Scal(){
        prepareCAL();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scal cal = new Scal();
        cal.showcontrols();
    }

    private void prepareCAL() {
        mainframe = new JFrame();
        mainframe.setSize(400, 400);
        mainframe.setBackground(Color.GRAY);        

        inputPanel = new JPanel(); 
        controlsPanel = new JPanel();
        controlsPanel.setSize(new Dimension(200, 250));

        opPanel = new JPanel();
        opPanel.setSize(200, 250);
//      opPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 250));

        mainframe.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainframe.add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainframe.add(opPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showcontrols() {
        inputbox = new JTextField(30);
        inputbox.setText("");

        inputPanel.add(inputbox);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("1");

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("2");

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("3");

        JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
        btn4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("4");

        JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
        btn5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("5");

        JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
        btn6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("6");

        JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
        btn7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("7");

        JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
        btn8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("8");

        JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
        btn9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("9");

        JButton btnclear = new JButton("C");
        btnclear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("c");

        JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
        btn0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("0");

        JButton btnequal = new JButton("=");
        btnequal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("=");

        controlsPanel.add(btn1);
        controlsPanel.add(btn2);
        controlsPanel.add(btn3);
        controlsPanel.add(btn4);
        controlsPanel.add(btn5);
        controlsPanel.add(btn6);        
        controlsPanel.add(btn7);
        controlsPanel.add(btn8);
        controlsPanel.add(btn9);
        controlsPanel.add(btnclear);
        controlsPanel.add(btn0);
        controlsPanel.add(btnequal);

        JButton btnPlus = new JButton("+");
        btnPlus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("+");

        JButton btnSub = new JButton("-");
        btnSub.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("-");

        JButton btnMul = new JButton("*");
        btnMul.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("*");

        JButton btnDiv = new JButton("/");
        btnDiv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        btn1.setActionCommand("/");

        btn1.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn2.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn3.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn4.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn5.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn6.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn7.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn8.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn9.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btn0.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btnPlus.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btnSub.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btnMul.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btnDiv.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btnclear.addActionListener(new ClickListener());
        btnequal.addActionListener(new ClickListener());


        opPanel.add(btnPlus);
        opPanel.add(btnSub);
        opPanel.add(btnMul);
        opPanel.add(btnDiv);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);     
    }

    private class ClickListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == "1"){
                inputbox.setText("1");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

i have used events to change value in textbox. i am making calculator. so is their other better way to make it? 
and how can i use this logic properly why it didt work. i only implemented it for 1 up till now. only only 1 should display in the textfield.
Help needed please

Comment: i also used { String c=e.getActionCommand(); e.equals("1")} but it didnt work

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this

```
if (e.getSource() == "1")
```

You want

```
JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
if ("1".equals(source.getActionCommand()))
```

Or just simply

```
if ("1".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
```

Another option is to check against the `JButton` object itself

```
JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
if (source == btn1) {}
```

Or simply

```
if (e.getSource() == btn1) {}
```

So you have options

---

**NOTE**

What `getSource()` return is the object that fired the `ActionEvent`, which is the `JButton` object. `JButton` will never `== "1"`. You need to get the `actionCommand` which returns a String and compare it to `"1"`

---

**UPDATE**

What you are doing is do this repeatedly

```
btn1.setActionCommand("1");
btn1.setActionCommand("2");
btn1.setActionCommand("3");
```

You're always setting the action command for `btn1`. You need to change them accordingly

Comment: It might be worth noting that `getSource()` returns the object that triggered the event. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: It might be better to use "1".equals(source.getActionCommand()) as actionCommand will return null by default +1

Comment: "1".equals(source.getActionCommand())    i used this
but didnt work for me

Comment: @assassino Is a recommendation to avoid possible `NullPointerExceptions` and reduce the need to use `== null &&` conditions within your `if` statements.  Didn't say it would fix you problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you need to use `invokeLater()` to start any Swing application.

and `e.getSource()` will return the reference of the button on which the action happened. If you want so stick to that, then it should be `== btn1`

Plus, the rules of making an SSCCE state that you strip your code down to the required minimum. Why do you have the extra code when all you have implemented is listener for.one button ?